# Access SQL: Union select, show both fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT Ph.Account, Ph.Ct FROM Ph
UNION SELECT Rx.Account, Rx.Ct FROM Rx;
```

Which works fine, but the Ph.Ct and Rx.Ct fields may not always be the same. So I wanted to display both of them, but the query is only showing 1 "Ct" field and not both.

How can I have it show both?

Here's `ph`:

```
12685      3
29568      1
38771      2
```

Here's `rx`:

```
10657      1
12685      2
68781      2
79874      1
```

What's what I want to come out from the query:

```
Account    ph.ct    rx.ct
10657               1
12685      3        2
29568      1
38771      2
68781               2
79874               1
```

A UNION gets the correct data set (about 800 results), but not the right fields. Any JOINs I've tried do not give the right data set (only about 300 results).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a full outer join.  For each value of `Account` appearing in either table, this will give the corresponding values of `Ct` for each table if the given value of `Account` appears and null otherwise.

```
select Account,Ph.Ct as ph_ct,Rx.Ct as rx_ct
from Ph full outer join Rx on (Ph.Account=Rx.Account);
```

**Edit:** Since Access apparently doesn't support full outer joins (for some god awful reason), you can achieve the same effect with the union of a left join with a right join:

```
select Ph.Account, Ph.Ct as ph_ct, Rx.Ct as rx_ct
from Ph left join Rx on (Ph.Account=Rx.Account)
union
select Rx.Account, Ph.Ct as ph_ct,Rx. Ct as rx_ct
from Ph right join Rx on (Ph.Account=Rx.Account);
```

which is also equivalent to (the probably faster):

```
select Ph.Account, Ph.Ct as ph_ct, Rx.Ct as rx_ct
from Ph left join Rx on (Ph.Account=Rx.Account)
where (Rx.Account IS NULL)
union all
select Rx.Account, Ph.Ct as ph_ct, Rx.Ct as rx_ct
from Ph right join Rx on (Ph.Account=Rx.Account);
```

Comment: I did try that, but that completely changes the data set. The SQL I posted gives 800 results which is right, and with the ALL it gives 1200 results which is not the result I need. Not only that, Access still only shows one "Ct" field with the ALL regardless.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question with some sample input and corresponding sample output so that I can understand what you're asking.

Comment: @JackBurace - So...you want a left join on `Account`, then?

Comment: I did try a join already, but that only returns ~400 results which is also wrong (I believe it only picks accounts which exist in both tables, which I don't want). I want the query to display all entries in both tables aside but not duplicates (but it still needs to list the account once, even if it's in both tables).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all entries in both tables aside but not duplicates".  Please give us sample input for **each** of `Ph` and `Rx` along with the corresponding sample output.

Comment: @JackBurace @JackManey: Sounds like this is a job for `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @ean5533 - Maybe...that'd be my next guess, but I want to figure out what the OP is asking first.

Comment: @JackManey: Except that FOJ isn't supported in ms access, so you'll have to do a left join union'd with a right join.

Comment: @JackBurace: Check also Remou's answer, it's equally good. Not sure about speed but it's surely more elegant.

Comment: @ypercube: More elegant? I'd say that's a matter of taste; the left-right-union seems much more elegant and logical to me, but I can understand that different minds think differently. However, as far as performance goes, left-right-union will crush Remou's answer (it requires full table scans on both tables and the results to be stored in memory as a combined temp table, and then indexes on the `account` columns can't be used for the joins).

Comment: @ean5533: Yes, I would bet on the `UNION ALL` for best performance in any DBMS.

Comment: You are right about the temp. table in Remou's answer but I don't think a full table scan is needed for the union subquery. More like a full index scan (if Access engine has that).

Comment: @ypercube Whoops, you're right, that's what I meant. No reason to scan the whole table on an indexed column. Still, the temp table won't be indexed which will slow down the subsequent joins

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a full outer join in MS Access, so:

```
SELECT m.Account, Ph.Ct, Rx.Ct FROM
((SELECT Ph.Account FROM Ph
UNION SELECT Rx.Account FROM Rx) As m
LEFT JOIN Ph ON m.Account = Ph.Account)
LEFT JOIN Rx ON m.Account = Rx.Account
```

Comment: Which makes more obvious why a `UNION` is similar to an `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Strange, this does not appear to give the right data set. It only returns ~400 which is not how many the UNION I posted returns (~800). I assume it's only returning entries that exist only in both tables, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jack Oops LEFT JOIN is what you want.

Comment: @Remou: This solution does not produce the equivalent of a full outer join. It requires matching records to be found in both `Ph` and `Rx`. You'll need to turn those `INNER JOIN`s into `LEFT JOIN`s, but at the point you're better off going with Jack Maney's answer for better performance.

Comment: @ean5533 In Access, you are not dealing with the kind of very large data sets where performance on this kind of query becomes an issue, unless you are using linked tables, in which case you are better off with a pass-through query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a `union`. You want a `join`. If you join the fields on Account, you can show the Rx.Ct and Ph.Ct as well.

In a `union`, it lists all the rows from one table, stacked on top of another table, excluding duplicates. Each row is from a different table.

In a `join`, each row is a combination of two tables, which means the columns that are not joined can hold different values.

Here you go:

```
SELECT Ph.Account, Ph.Ct, Rx.Ct FROM Ph INNER JOIN Rx ON Ph.Account=Rx.Account;
```

Comment: This doesn't give the same data set as the UNION I posted. Mine gives ~800 (which is right) and this gave ~400. The data set needs to be the same, just the other fields need to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `join`, not a `union`:

```
select
    coalesce(Ph.Account, Rx.Account) as Account
    Ph.Ct,
    Rx.Ct
from
    Ph
    full outer join Rx on
        Ph.Account = Rx.Account
```

You can change `inner` to the type of join you want. Read more about the different types of joins [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

`union`s are used when you want to take one set of results and append them to the rowset of another result. `join`s are used when you want to take one set of results and append them to the columnset of another result.

Comment: I did try an inner join already, but that only returns ~300 records which isn't what I want. I want the query to return all entries in both tables, aside from duplicates (but still include an entry that is in both tables, once).

Comment: I don't think a `full join` exists in Access, as mentioned in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future references about UNION Operator:

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Note: The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

For more info: [UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)